# set c of convergent sequences in the Normed Linear Space of all bounded real sequences under the sup norm is complete

Tags: metric-spaces

Show that the set c of convergent sequences in the Normed Linear Space of all bounded real sequences under the sup norm is complete

my try: I know that the set of all bounded functions from a set X to R under the sup norm is complete.So the problem reduces to showing that the set c is closed

But I cant do that.Any hints.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that a Cauchy sequence of sequences is Cauchy "component-wise".

If you have a Cauchy sequence $(x_n^k)_{k=1}^\infty$ of bounded sequences I would show that after fixing an $n$, the sequence $(x_{n}^k)_{k=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathbb{F}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and hence it converges to some $x_{n} \in \mathbb{F}$. Then show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} (x_n^k) = x_n$. Also, you need to show $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence.